# Peg solitaire solution with DFS gives segmentation fault

Tags: c, algorithm, segmentation-fault, depth-first-search

**The Algorithm**

[image: Algorithm Pseducode:]

Each possible configuration of the Peg Solitaire (Pegsol) is a tuple made of: m × m grid
board, the
position of the cursor and whether the peg under the cursor has been selected. This tuple is
called
a state. The Pegsol Graph G = <V, E> is implicitly defined. The vertex set V is defined as all
the
possible configurations (states), and the edges E connecting two vertexes are defined by the
legal jump
actions (right, left, up, down).
Your task is to find the path leading to the best solution, i.e. leading to the vertex (state) with
the
least number of remaining pegs. A path is a sequence of actions. You are going to use
Depth First
Search to find the best solution, up to a maximum budget of expanded/explored nodes
(nodes for
which you’ve generated its children).
When the AI solver is called (Algorithm 1 ), it should explore all possible paths (sequence of
jump
actions) following a Depth First Search (DFS) strategy, until consuming the budget or until a
path
solving the game is found. Note that we do not include duplicate states in the search. If a
state was
already generated, we will not include it again in the stack (line 21 ). The algorithm should
return the
best solution found, the path leading to the least number of remaining pegs. This path will
then
be executed by the game engine.
You might have multiple paths leading to a solution. Your algorithm should consider the
possible action by scanning the board in this order: traverse coordinate x = 0,....., m first, and
then y = 0, … , m looking for a peg that can jump, and then selecting jumping actions left,
right, up or down.
Make sure you manage the memory well. When you finish running the algorithm, you have
to free all
the nodes from the memory, otherwise you will have memory leaks. You will notice that the
algorithm
can run out of memory fairly fast after expanding a few million nodes.
When you applyAction you have to create a new node, that

1. points to the parent,
2. updates the state with the action chosen,
3. updates the depth of the node.
4. updates the action used to create the node

I'm implementing this algorithm with the following code:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <math.h>

#include "ai.h"
#include "utils.h"
#include "hashtable.h"
#include "stack.h"


void copy_state(state_t* dst, state_t* src){
    
    //Copy field
    memcpy( dst->field, src->field, SIZE*SIZE*sizeof(int8_t) );

    dst->cursor = src->cursor;
    dst->selected = src->selected;
}

/**
 * Saves the path up to the node as the best solution found so far
*/
void save_solution( node_t* solution_node ){
    node_t* n = solution_node;
    while( n->parent != NULL ){
        copy_state( &(solution[n->depth]), &(n->state) );
        solution_moves[n->depth-1] = n->move;

        n = n->parent;
    }
    solution_size = solution_node->depth;
}


node_t* create_init_node( state_t* init_state ){
    node_t * new_n = (node_t *) malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    new_n->parent = NULL;   
    new_n->depth = 0;
    copy_state(&(new_n->state), init_state);
    return new_n;
}

/**
 * Apply an action to node n and return a new node resulting from executing the action
*/
node_t* applyAction(node_t* n, position_s* selected_peg, move_t action ){

    node_t* new_node = NULL;
    
    //printf("PASS#");
    //FILL IN MISSING CODE
    
    new_node = create_init_node( &(n->state));
    
    new_node->parent = n;
    
    n->depth = n->depth + 1;

    execute_move_t( &(new_node->state), &(new_node->state.cursor), action );
    
    return new_node;

}


// From here my implementation starts
/**
 * Find a solution path as per algorithm description in the handout
 */

void find_solution( state_t* init_state  ){

    HashTable table;
    int8_t x,y;
    int remainingPegs;

    // Choose initial capacity of PRIME NUMBER 
    // Specify the size of the keys and values you want to store once 
    ht_setup( &table, sizeof(int8_t) * SIZE * SIZE, sizeof(int8_t) * SIZE * SIZE, 16769023);

    // Initialize Stack
    initialize_stack();

    //Add the initial node
    node_t* n = create_init_node( init_state );
    node_t* new_node = NULL;
    
    //FILL IN THE GRAPH ALGORITHM
    stack_push(n);
    remainingPegs = num_pegs(&(n->state));
    while(!is_stack_empty())
    {
        
        n = stack_top();
        
        expanded_nodes = expanded_nodes + 1;
        if(num_pegs(&(n->state)) < remainingPegs )
        {
            save_solution(n);
            remainingPegs = num_pegs(&(n->state));
            
        }
        
        for (x=0;x<SIZE;x++) {
            for (y=0;y<SIZE;y++) {
                 enum moves_e a = left;
                    
                if(can_apply(&(n->state),&(n->state.cursor),a)){
                    printf("World cup");
                    node_t* new_node = applyAction(n,&(n->state.cursor),a);
                    generated_nodes = generated_nodes + 1;
                    //printf("%d",generated_nodes);
                }
                a = right;
                if(can_apply(&(n->state),&(n->state.cursor),a)){
                    printf("World cup");
                    node_t* new_node = applyAction(n,&(n->state.cursor),a);
                    generated_nodes = generated_nodes + 1;
                    //printf("%d",generated_nodes);
                }
                a = up;
                if(can_apply(&(n->state),&(n->state.cursor),a)){
                    printf("World cup");
                    node_t* new_node = applyAction( n,&(n->state.cursor),a);
                    generated_nodes = generated_nodes + 1;
                    //printf("%d",generated_nodes);
                }
                a = down;
                if(can_apply(&(n->state),&(n->state.cursor),a)){
                    node_t* new_node = applyAction( n,&(n->state.cursor),a);
                    generated_nodes = generated_nodes + 1;
                    //printf("%d",generated_nodes);
                }
                //Comment line number 134 here where segmentation fault occured
                if (won(&(new_node->state)))
                {
                    //save_solution(new_node);
                    //remainingPegs = num_pegs(&(new_node->state));
                    //free_stack();
                    break;
                }
                
                if(new_node->depth == 0)
                {
                    stack_push(new_node);
                }
                
                if(expanded_nodes >= budget)
                    break;
                
            }
        }
        
            
    }
}
```

And another helper methods are present in util.c are mentioned below:

```
#include "utils.h"
#include "layouts.h"

void execute_move_t(state_t* state, position_s* selected_peg, move_t jump) {
    int8_t x = selected_peg->x;
    int8_t y = selected_peg->y;

    
    switch (jump) {
    case up:          //Jump up
        state->field[x][y-2] = 'o';
        state->field[x][y-1] = '.';
        state->field[x][y-0] = '.';
        state->cursor.y = y-2;
        break;

    case down:         //Jump down
        state->field[x][y+0] = '.';
        state->field[x][y+1] = '.';
        state->field[x][y+2] = 'o';
        state->cursor.y = y+2;
        break;

    case left:         //Jump left
        state->field[x-2][y] = 'o';
        state->field[x-1][y] = '.';
        state->field[x-0][y] = '.';
        state->cursor.x = x-2;
        break;

    case right:          //Jump right
        state->field[x+0][y] = '.';
        state->field[x+1][y] = '.';
        state->field[x+2][y] = 'o';
        state->cursor.x = x+2;
        break;

    }
    
}

bool can_apply(state_t *board, position_s* selected_peg, move_t jump){
    
    
    //printf("%d",jump);
    // Can select a Peg
    
    if ( board->field[ selected_peg->x ][ selected_peg->y ] !='o')  return false;
    
    //Determine if move is legal
    switch (jump) {
        case up:    
            //printf("Up");
            if(  selected_peg->y < 2) return false;
            if( board->field[ selected_peg->x ][ selected_peg->y - 1 ] !='o')  return false;
            if( board->field[ selected_peg->x ][ selected_peg->y - 2 ] !='.')  return false;
            printf("Up");
            break;
            
        case down:    
            //printf("Down");
            if( selected_peg->y > SIZE - 3 ) return false;
            if( board->field[ selected_peg->x ][ selected_peg->y + 1 ] !='o')  return false;
            if( board->field[ selected_peg->x ][ selected_peg->y + 2 ] !='.')  return false;
            printf("Down");
            break;

        case left:    
            //printf("Left");
            if( selected_peg->x < 2) return false;
            if( board->field[ selected_peg->x - 1 ][ selected_peg->y ] !='o')  return false;
            if( board->field[ selected_peg->x - 2 ][ selected_peg->y ] !='.')  return false;
            break;

        case right:   
            //printf("Right");
            if( selected_peg->x > SIZE - 3) return false;
            if( board->field[ selected_peg->x + 1 ][ selected_peg->y ] !='o')  return false;
            if( board->field[ selected_peg->x + 2 ][ selected_peg->y ] !='.')  return false;
            printf("Right");
            break;
    }
    // Can Jump

    
    return true;

}


bool won(state_t *board) {
    int8_t x,y;
    int8_t count=0;

    for (x=0;x<SIZE;x++) {
        for (y=0;y<SIZE;y++) {
            if (board->field[x][y]=='o') {
                count++;
             
            }
            // If more than one peg is left, you haven't won yet
            if( count > 1) return false;
        }
    }
    //If only one is left
    return count == 1;

}

int num_pegs( state_t *board ){
    int count = 0;
    for (int y=0;y<SIZE;y++) {
        for (int x=0;x<SIZE;x++) {
            count+=board->field[x][y]=='o';
        }
    }
    return count;
}


void rotateBoard(state_t *board) {
    int8_t i,j,n=SIZE;
    int8_t tmp;
    for (i=0; i<n/2; i++){
        for (j=i; j<n-i-1; j++){
            tmp = board->field[i][j];
            board->field[i][j] = board->field[j][n-i-1];
            board->field[j][n-i-1] = board->field[n-i-1][n-j-1];
            board->field[n-i-1][n-j-1] = board->field[n-j-1][i];
            board->field[n-j-1][i] = tmp;
        }
    }
    i = board->cursor.x;
    j = board->cursor.y;

    board->cursor.x = -(j-n/2)+n/2;
    board->cursor.y = (i-n/2)+n/2;
}

bool select_peg(state_t *board) {
    int8_t x,y,(*field)[SIZE];
    bool selected;

    x = board->cursor.x;
    y = board->cursor.y;
    field = board->field;
    selected = board->selected;

    if (field[x][y]!='o') return false;
    board->selected = !selected;
    return true;
}

bool moveUp(state_t *board) {
    int8_t x,y,(*field)[SIZE];
    bool selected;

    x = board->cursor.x;
    y = board->cursor.y;
    field = board->field;
    selected = board->selected;

    if (selected) {
        if (y<2) return false;
        if (field[x][y-2]!='.') return false;
        if (field[x][y-1]!='o') return false;
        if (field[x][y-0]!='o') return false;
        field[x][y-2] = 'o';
        field[x][y-1] = '.';
        field[x][y-0] = '.';
        board->cursor.y = y-2;
        board->selected = false;
    } else {
        if (y<1) return false;
        if (field[x][y-1]==' ') return false;
        board->cursor.y = y-1;
    }
    return true;
}

bool moveLeft(state_t *board) {
    bool success;
    rotateBoard(board);
    success = moveUp(board);
    rotateBoard(board);
    rotateBoard(board);
    rotateBoard(board);
    return success;
}

bool moveDown(state_t *board) {
    bool success;
    rotateBoard(board);
    rotateBoard(board);
    success = moveUp(board);
    rotateBoard(board);
    rotateBoard(board);
    return success;
}

bool moveRight(state_t *board) {
    bool success;
    rotateBoard(board);
    rotateBoard(board);
    rotateBoard(board);
    success = moveUp(board);
    rotateBoard(board);
    return success;
}


int8_t validMovesUp(state_t *board) {
    int8_t x,y;
    int8_t count=0;
    for (x=0;x<SIZE;x++) {
        for (y=SIZE-1;y>1;y--) {
            if (board->field[x][y]=='o') {
                if (board->field[x][y-1]=='o') {
                    if (board->field[x][y-2]=='.') {
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}

bool gameEndedForHuman(state_t *board) {
    int8_t i,count=0;
    for (i=0;i<4;i++) {
        count+=validMovesUp(board);
        rotateBoard(board);
    }
    return count==0;
}

void initialize(state_t *board, int8_t layout) {
    int8_t x,y;

    if( layout > NUM_LAYOUTS - 1) layout = 0;
    
    board->cursor.x = 4;
    board->cursor.y = 4;
    board->selected = false;

    memset(board->field,0,sizeof(board->field));
    for (y=0;y<SIZE;y++) {
        for (x=0;x<SIZE;x++) {
            board->field[x][y]=configuration[layout][y][x*2];
        }
    }
}


void drawBoard(state_t *board) {
    int8_t x,y,count=0;

    // move cursor to home position
    printf("\033[H");

    for (y=0;y<SIZE;y++) {
        for (x=0;x<SIZE;x++) {
            count+=board->field[x][y]=='o';
        }
    }
    printf("peg-solitaire.c %7d pegs\n",count);
    printf("                             \n");

    for (y=0;y<SIZE;y++) {
        for (x=0;x<14-SIZE;x++) {
            printf(" ");
        }
        for (x=0;x<SIZE;x++) {
            if (board->cursor.x == x && board->cursor.y == y) {
                if (board->selected) {
                    printf("\b|\033[7m%c\033[27m|",board->field[x][y]);
                } else {
                    printf("\033[7m%c\033[27m ",board->field[x][y]);
                }
            } else {
                printf("%c ",board->field[x][y]);
            }
        }
        for (x=0;x<14-SIZE;x++) {
            printf(" ");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("                            \n");
    printf("   arrow keys, q or enter   \n");
    printf("\033[A"); // one line up
}

char* action_cstr(move_t move){

    switch (move) {
        case up:  
            return "Up";
        break;

        case down: 
            return "Down";
        break;

        case left:    
            return "Left";
        break;

        case right:  
            return "Right";
        break;

    }
    return " ";
}

void print_solution(){

    for(int i=0; i< solution_size; i++)
        printf("    %d - %s                              \n", i+1, action_cstr(solution_moves[i]));
        
}

void play_solution(){
    for(int i=0; i <= solution_size; i++){
        drawBoard(&(solution[i]));
        usleep(500000);
        
        if( i < solution_size){
            //Reverse action
            switch ( solution_moves[i] ) {
                case up:          
                    solution[i].cursor.y = solution[i+1].cursor.y+2;
                    solution[i].cursor.x = solution[i+1].cursor.x;
                    break;
                case down:          
                    solution[i].cursor.y = solution[i+1].cursor.y-2;
                    solution[i].cursor.x = solution[i+1].cursor.x;
                    break;
                case left:         
                    solution[i].cursor.x = solution[i+1].cursor.x+2;
                    solution[i].cursor.y = solution[i+1].cursor.y;
                    break;
                case right:          
                    solution[i].cursor.x = solution[i+1].cursor.x-2;
                    solution[i].cursor.y = solution[i+1].cursor.y;
                    break;
                }
            solution[i].selected = true;
            drawBoard(&(solution[i]));
            usleep(500000);
        }
    }
}
```

It results in a segmentation fault. Please, anyone, help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: You need to run the code in a debugger. The debugger will tell you which line is generating the seg fault.

Comment: I have identified line number 134 because it's not creating the new node @user3386109

Comment: Put a comment at the end of line 134 that says `// this is line 134`.

Comment: Added the comment

Comment: The first thing you need to know is that `node_t* new_node = NULL;` at the top of `find_solution` declares a variable that is never used again (except to cause the seg fault). All of the lines `node_t* new_node = applyAction()` are creating new variables. Those lines are **not** updating the variable that you declared at the top of the function.